# Angular login request to Spring rest with security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-rest

I am very new in Spring security. I am confused about the Spring rest security but could not find any full solution. I have following scenario:

1) I have created the angular js service which makes a $http call to the spring rest.

2) I want spring security to intercept this url(/login) and give me response back accordingly.

What I tried if I am accessing the url directly http://localhost:8123/SpringMVC/login then its working fine, it's asking for username and password and after entering the correct user, password I got the result but same thing I am doing from AngularJs; it's giving me the following error

```
angular.js:10514 OPTIONS http://localhost:8123/SpringMVC/rest/login/ (anonymous function) @ angular.js:10514sendReq @ angular.js:10333serverRequest @ angular.js:10045processQueue @ angular.js:14567(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14583$eval @ angular.js:15846$digest @ angular.js:15657$apply @ angular.js:15951bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1633invoke @ angular.js:4450doBootstrap @ angular.js:1631bootstrap @ angular.js:1651angularInit @ angular.js:1545(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28359trigger @ angular.js:2996eventHandler @ angular.js:3271
localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8111/SpringMVC/rest/categories/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8234' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Please suggest how to configure the header correctly in fronend as well as backend both angular and rest application are running on different server.

This is in SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .httpBasic()
          .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();


    }
```

This is what I am doing in Entry Point:

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //prevent default behaviour
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
         response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    " Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,AUTH-TOKEN");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("hello from server");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding-

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Also update

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    " Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,AUTH-TOKEN");
```

to

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,AUTH-TOKEN, Authorization");`
```

Comment: thanks kushagra but problem is same ,do I add to add the headers in angular side also beacuase if I directly access the Server url its asking for username and password and showing the correct page but from angular how I will send username and password to resolve it.

Comment: Request type is xhr for your information and the error I am getting is custom code I mentioned in backend code 401.

Comment: I configured the correct header in angular and its work now thank for reply.